Allow access to page with a variable in the url in laravel
An URL is generated from a view like this
(http://127.0.0.1:8000/mypage?view=id)
where id= variable
I want to deny access to the url if someone tries to access the page without the variable. Something like this (http://127.0.0.1:8000/mypage)
Current Route for the blade is:
Route::get('/mypage', [PageController::class, 'pageFunction']);

What have you tried ? did you make a middleware ?

I tried to pass the variable through the route (as per many results on google) by doing Route::get('/mypage?view={id}', [PageController::class, 'pageFunction']);  but that leads to another undefined variable that is currently working fine without the url variable.

make a middleware and check for $request->input('view') and its value if you need to before deciding to return $next($request) or throw a 404 https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#defining-middleware checking for right to access is the role of middlewares

I think doing it like that only works for segments.
You should probably create a Middleware, Route::filter, RequestObject (use that in the controller, or do it in the controller directly.
Those are some of the options you have to do this.
Route::filtter is probably easies/ straigtforward

Hi, you could also use another approach,
Route::get('/mypage/{view}', [PageController::class, 'pageFunction'])->where(['view'=>'[0-9]+']);, the view value with curly braces is required and also uses where() to specify the data type

The issue was solved after adding this on the controller if($request->has('view')){}. Thanks everyone.
